# VMWare Workstation - Set maximum size and what will be the consequences?

Tags: vmware

Our vm file doesn't have a maximum size. We didn't get to set one. The file size is now atleast 120GB.
What can we do to stop it from growing? Do we need to set a maximum file size and if we do, what would be the consequences? Will it automatically delete unused files?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Maximum size in Virtual Machine Settings. Select Hard Disk. Find Utilities
under Utilities there is a option called Expand
You Can Set Maximum Disk Size
you can't decrease Maximum size VMware Only Allows to Increase

Also You can Set Custom Maximum Disk Size when you creating Virtual Machine You can Try Re Creating Machine if Possible

Comment: what happens if we set a maximum size? what will happen to the unused files?

Comment: our vm file size is around 120GB if we set it to for example just 90GB what will happen to those 30GB file? Is it going to compress the files to fit the 90GB?

Comment: You Cant Size Limit 120Gb Disk to 90 Gb You Can Only Increase the Size No Decresing Possible,

Comment: how does VMWare manage the size, will it tell us it can't start the VM because the allocated size is full?